# why when I use spinner the angular sort and paginator material it does not work

Tags: angular, angular-material, frontend, angular-material-table

I want to ask why when I user spinner the  the angular sort and paginator material it does not work
but before I use it every thing was work successfully also when I delete the *ngIf related to the spinner everything work okay

this my table code html

```
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1">
  <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
</div>
<div class="col"  *ngIf="!loading">
  <h1 >Manage Employees</h1>
  <br>
  <div class="row" >
  <mat-form-field class="col">
   <input #filterInput matInput (keyup)="applyFilter()" placeholder="Search">
  </mat-form-field>
  <div class="col" >
  <button class="btn"
  style="color:white; border: none; font-size: small; background:linear-gradient(150deg, rgba(153,226,180,1) 0%, rgba(120,198,163,1) 50%, rgba(86,171,145,1) 67%);
  " (click)="createemployee()"><fa-icon [icon]="addemployee" style="color:white;"></fa-icon>Add Employee</button></div>
</div>
  <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8" >
    <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>NO.</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row;let index = index" data-label="NO.">{{index+1}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="fullName">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" data-label="Name">{{row.fullName}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Email</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" data-label="Email">{{row.email}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="phoneNumber">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Phone</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" data-label="Phone">{{row.phoneNumber}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="isActive">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Activate</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" data-label="Activate">
        <i *ngIf="row.isActive === false">Deactive</i>
        <i *ngIf="row.isActive === true">Active</i></mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="dateOfBirth">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Birthday</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" data-label="Birthday">{{row.dateOfBirth|date}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="address">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Addres</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" data-label="Addres">{{row.address}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Action">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Action</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" data-label="Action">
        <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu">
          <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
          <button  (click)="onEditClick(row)"  mat-menu-item>
            <mat-icon style="color:#1c6159;">edit</mat-icon>
            <span>Edit</span>
          </button>
          <button *ngIf="row.isActive ===false" (click)="userStatus(row)" mat-menu-item>
            <mat-icon  style="color:#1c6159;">check_circle_outline</mat-icon>
            <span>Active</span>
          </button>
          <button *ngIf="row.isActive ===true" (click)="userStatus(row)" mat-menu-item>
            <mat-icon style="color:#1c6159;">highlight_off</mat-icon>
            <span>Deactive</span>
          </button>
        </mat-menu>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns:columns;"></mat-row>

    </mat-table>
    <mat-paginator style="color:#1c6159;" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
  </div>
</div>
<div  class="text-center w-100 " *ngIf="loading">
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <app-spinner></app-spinner>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

and this the ts of table

```
import { Component,ElementRef,OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { faUserPlus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { AddEmployeeComponent } from 'src/app/components/add-employee/add-employee.component';
import { EditeUsersComponent } from 'src/app/components/edite-users/edite-users.component';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';

interface IEmployees{
  "id": string,
            "fullName":string,
            "username": string,
            "email": string,
            "phoneNumber":string,
            "password":string,
            "dateOfBirth":string,
            "userType": number,
            "userImage": null,
            "address": string,
            "isActive": boolean
            "index":number
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-manage-employees',
  templateUrl: './manage-employees.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./manage-employees.component.css']
})
export class ManageEmployeesComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource:MatTableDataSource<any>
  Employees: IEmployees[];
  columns: string[]=['id','fullName','email','phoneNumber','dateOfBirth','isActive','address','Action']
  addemployee=faUserPlus
  Active:boolean
  loading:boolean=true
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort,{static:true}) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild('filterInput') filterInput: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

  constructor(private dialog:MatDialog,private service:AuthService,
    private route:Router,
    private toaster:ToastrService,){

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getEmployee()

  }


  applyFilter() {
    // const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value // Remove whitespace
    //  this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    // const filterValue = this.filterInput.nativeElement.value;
    // this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
      const filterValue = this.filterInput.nativeElement.value.trim().toLowerCase();
      this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: IEmployees, filterValue) => {
        if (filterValue === ('Active'.trim().toLowerCase())) {
          return data.isActive===true;
        }else if(filterValue === ('deactive'.trim().toLowerCase())){
         return data.isActive===false;
        }
        return (
          data.fullName.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) ||
          data.email.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) ||
          data.phoneNumber.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) ||
          data.dateOfBirth.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) ||
          data.address.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
        );
      };
      this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;

  }

  getEmployee(){
    this.loading=true
    this.service.getEmployees().subscribe((res:any)=>{
      this.Employees=res.data
      this.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource(this.Employees);
      this.dataSource.sort=this.sort;
      this.dataSource.paginator=this.paginator
      this.loading=false })
  }
```

I have no idea why and how to fix it